# why some time query data in realm return empty?

Tags: android, realm

i has been saved my data to realm. but some time result is empty. if i found 5 times maybe has 1 time result empty. this my source:

```
 realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
 Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmResults<RealmMenuSet> realmMenu =
    realm.where(RealmMenuSet.class).equalTo("restaurantID",   restaurantID).findAll();
```

some time realmMenu is empty. i used realm 1.1.0

Comment: Are you building a new config every time?

Comment: yes, every time i Query data!

Comment: why would you do that? Do you know what that does?

Comment: You should set the default configuration **once** in the entire application. You should also open either one Realm per thread, or one Realm per activity. Not "one by query".

Comment: i don't know i just follow document.
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: You copy some code, you don't know what it does, it doesn't do what you want, and you are surprised. Weird huh? You should read the rest of the documentation as well, also this part https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#the-default-realmconfiguration